# Can't count pagination of pdf page number Using counter(page) and counter(pages) are page counters that are built into CSS

Tags: java, html, css, apache-velocity

I have a html template report and **data populate using Apache velocity** Here i added a footer, In the footer section pagination page number will show but it shows **Page 0 of 0** i don't why this happen.

following the link code i have used.
[text](https://community.jamasoftware.com/blogs/robin-calhoun/2020/07/13/quick-start-html-templates-for-velocity-pdf-report#AddHeaderFooter)

i write this code below

**Css**

```
#pageNumber::after {
   content: counter(page)
}

#totalPages::after {
   content: counter(pages)
}
```

**Html**

```
 Page <span id="pageNumber"></span> of <span id="totalPages"></span>
```